# Connecting two monitors through single thunderbolt 3 port

Tags: multiple-monitors, thunderbolt

I have Lenovo C940 Yoga 2-in-1 which comes with two Thunderbolt 3 ports.
I also have [Lenovo USB-C 3-in-1 Hub](https://www.lenovo.com/in/en/accessories-and-monitors/cables-and-adapters/adapters/CABLE-BO-USB-C-3-in-1-Hub-ROW/p/GX90T33021).
This is image on above link:
[image]
But when I connect two monitors to thunderbolt, one from HDMI and another through VGA, the two monitors are actually mirrored, not fully extended. That is, when I click identify in Display settings, it flashes same number on both of them. Laptop displays number 1, and two external monitors displays number 2 as can be seen in [this video](https://youtu.be/cjSuf_Nryqg).

But, I felt, laptop screen should show number 1, one of external monitors should display number 2 and the other monitor should display number 3. But that is not the case it seems. Why is it so?

Also note that Display settings window shows only two displays and that second display is basically both of two monitors:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Windows Key + P, press Extend. You may also have to manually set the other monitor to force it as the third monitor.

I've only ever used 1 monitor, I can't back up my information. Someone else will more than certainly post a more detailed explanation here, wait a few minutes.

Comment: Doing WindowsKey+P and then clicking Extend causes what I have described in question. With duplicate, all the three screens would have shown number 1 on clicking identify in Display settings. And what do you mean "manually set the other monitor to force it as the third monitor"?

Comment: Go to Display Settings, click on one of the monitors that are marked as 2. Scroll down, force it to extend instead of mirror, and it should be fixed. This is happening because the same thunderbolt port is being used for 2 monitors, which is not its intentional design.

Comment: I could only see only two displays in Display settings. 1st of them is laptop and 2nd one corresponds to both monitors. I have updated the question with screenshot at the end.

Comment: Oooh, I see. Somebody else will have to answer, I can't solve that for you. Apologies